# How do I find points where two functions do not interesect?

Tags: functions

I have the question;
Consider the functions $f_k$, where k $\in$ R and:
$$f_k:[0,\infty)\rightarrow R, f(x)=\sqrt x +k $$
For what value(s) of k do the graphs of $f_k$ and $f_k^{-1}$ have no point of intersection?

I figured I would have to use the discriminant to find the value of k but ended up with the equation $x^4-4x^2k^2+k^4-k^2-x$ that isnt in the $ax^2 +bx +c$ format and am unsure what to do.

Comment: Ummm.... find where they *do* intersect, and then...

Answer (score 1):

If we draw a picture, bearing in mind that the graph of $f_k^{-1}$ is the graph of $f$ reflected about the line $y=x$, we see that for $k\ge 0$, the graphs have two points of intersection; and for sufficiently negative $k$, the graphs have no point of intersection.

You want to find the borderline case where the two graphs meet on the line $y=x$. For this case, the equation
$$\sqrt x+k=x$$ has exactly one solution. Express this as a quadratic, and set the discriminant equal to $0$. This gives you the borderline value of $k$; and for all smaller values of $k$, the graphs have no point of intersection.